# Can anyone explain why my workflow designer is so messed up?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, workflow-foundation-4

I'm trying to learn TFSBuild 2010 and workflows and I found using the designer was very confusing. Then I realized from seeing screenshots of other peoples workflows, my designer is clearly messed up. Take a look at this:

  https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DN6Y.png

Something is very strange here. As I click on each task the borders for that task show up but this can get extremely confusing when there is a lot going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your designer is messed up.  Why?  Dunno.

First thing I'd do is update your graphics card.  WPF is sensitive to bad video drivers.

Second is to go to Tools-Options and check out the Workflow options.  You can change the "theme" of the workflow there.  Change the theme, restart it and see if that makes a difference.  If it works, you can try going back to the other theme.

Lastly, I'd definitely open a Connect on this.  Check for the link under the Help menu.

Comment: I think some kind of unknown theme was somehow installed. I had been working with the blend theme I've seen floating around the internet but this problem occurred. Resetting all of my visual studio options and themes or default seemed to resolve the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that the XAML file for your workflow has invalid markup and is corrupted?  Does it look the same when you create a new/empty workflow?

I'd say that if its happening for all workflows, including new ones, then you probably should try posting on a Microsoft help forum like [this one](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/category/visualstudio,vsarch,vsdbg,vstest,vstfs,vsdata,vsappdev,visualbasic,visualcsharp,visualc).

Answer (score 0):

Can you show your XAML file?  Seems that it has more to do with the rendering of the Rehoster.